# Extra Characters in ByteArrayOutputStream() result Java

Tags: java, junit, bytearrayoutputstream, printstream

java

```
public class Hello {
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello world!");
        }

}
```

Class to test the result:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

import java.io.*;

public class TestHello {

    @Test
    public void testHelloWorld()
    {
        System.out.println("Test started");
        PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(bos));

        // action
        Hello.main(null);

        // undo the binding in System
        System.setOut(originalOut);

        //result check
        String t=bos.toString();
        for(int i =0; i<t.length();i++){
            System.out.println(t.charAt(i)+"*");
        }
        System.out.println(t.length());

        System.out.println("Test ended");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Test started 
H* 
e* 
l* 
l* 
o*  
* 
w* 
o* 
r* 
l* 
d* 
!*
 *

 * 
14 
Test ended
```

How to get rid of space between * and * above 14. Is there a way to do this in better way, so that this extra character will not appear?

Ideally t="Hello world!\n", but that's not the case.

Comment: There is no ‘extra space’. There is a newline, the result of you calling `println()`. If you don’t want the newline, don’t call a method that produces one. If you’re expecting the string to look the way it would look it Java source code, adjust your expectations. It won’t.

Comment: Replace your manual output with a proper assertion (`assertEquals("Hello world!\n", bos.toString());`) and you'll see that the test passes.

Comment: When I run your code I don't see the line with the extra space...

Comment: Are you using Windows? Windows uses `\r\n` for newlines, so this might be the `\r`?

Comment: There is an extra something. If you compare String h="Hello world!\n"; with my t they are not equal to each other. Question is why and how to make them equal? The hello.java printed h as is, bos.toString() has extra character and it seems to be extra "\n"?

Comment: `\r`? Have you considered printing its numerical value to *find out* what it is for yourself? And why do you *want* to make them equal? Line termination is platform-dependent. You don’t have any business testing for a specific one.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows! Thank you so much! It the \r... I guess I should just move back to linux!

Comment: Writing authograder for my class through a new platform... So I need to be able to run the code on their platform and compare results...

Comment: What you should do is read it via `readLine()` to get rid of the line terminations and compare the actual lines.

Comment: Thank you to all of you! My problem is resolved.

Comment: Your class? You’re teaching? With this level of knowledge? Really?

Answer (score -1):

You have

```
System.out.println(t.charAt(i)+"*");
```

and you will need to make sure that you only println it if it's appropriate. For example, you could have something like this in your loop:

```
char somechars[] = {'\n', '\r'};
```

and then

```
if (somechars.indexOf(t.charAt(i)) == -1) System.out.println(t.charAt(i)+"*");
```

so if your blacklist of chars you don't want to show contains the character, then you don't print it, otherwise you print it.